# Change Authentication Type of an MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have developed a fully working MVC 5 website with selecting its authentication as "Individual User Accounts", now I want to change it to use "Organizational User Accounts-On premise" to incorporate it with our AD via ADFS.

One thing I have done is commenting out the following in the Startup.cs file

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(OneJksbFrontOfficeWebApp.Startup))]
namespace OneJksbFrontOfficeWebApp
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //http://alkalinemedia.com/mvc5-infinite-loop-to-login-page/
            //ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything else I should do?
And where can I assign the On-Premise Authority Value?

Thanks

Comment: I think its safe to start with the template 'Organizational User Accounts-On premise' and add your changes accordingly. otherwise you will have to change lot of places, and you might end-up with lot of unused login files as well.

Comment: @rawel thanks for your comment. Lets say I opened a new project with Organization User Account-On Premise template. but how am I able to import all the items from my original projects. Is there a one-way thing or should I include one-by-one. Sorry If my question looks bit stupid, but I am still new to this..